# How to create custom map in AOE3?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

I am playing game **The Age of Empire III** in which I am creating a custom map but there is no open to create it, I found one option which is **creating scenario** which doesn't come up in custom map.

I found few clues about it but not the clear information.

So I am asking:

*How to create a Custom Map in Age of Empire III?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's rather complex.

You can create a scenario ingame, but in order to create a custom map, you must obtain a certain skill: RMS. It's the abbreviation for Random Map Scripting. There's no editor out there to create a custom map in AOE3, you must do it all by yourself, you must write it yourself.

If you really are eager to learn that, you can visit those sources:

- [An overview about the process of creating a custom map in AOE3.](http://www.ehow.com/how_7337361_make-maps-_age-empires-iii_.html)
- [Library about RMS.](http://aom.heavengames.com/scendesign/rms)
- [Forum about RMS concerning AOE3.](http://aoe3.heavengames.com/downloads/lister.php?category=rms)

If you follow everything written down there, you are ready to go and you can start off by creating a cool map. Wish you good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Click onto 'Help and Tools' on the main menu and then click into 'Scenario Editor' should give you a blank map to start from